# How can I disable breaking on user-unhandled exceptions in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, unit-testing, windows-phone-7, exception

The most common advice I find is to disable them via the `Debug > Exceptions` dialog. I've done this, but VS2010 still breaks on all user-unhandled exception. This is particularly annoying during unit tests that expect certain exceptions. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the built-in test runner and `MSTest`. First, make sure you are not running the tests in debug mode. Additionally, this problem can be circumvented by running the tests using the (run) keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>T</kbd>

  Runs test(s) in context (i.e. where your cursor is located, in a method, class, or namespace)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd>

  Runs all tests in an assembly

> **NOTE:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will debug tests.

Comment: I'm actually not using the built-in test runner. As I understand things, Silverlight UTF for Windows Phone has no Visual Studio Integration. I'm using the assemblies from here (http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/06/updated-ut-mango-bits/), as recommended by the book "Windows Phone 7.5 Unleashed".

Comment: Oh, and I'm not running the tests in Debug mode (I am running them in Release mode).